# The compiler still thinks "x" is undefined inside "if (x !== undefined)" block

Tags: typescript

I'm writing an Event Manager package, but I'm having some problems with the typing.

Look at this code:

```js
class Observable<T> {
    // pretend that I wrote some very nice code here
}

function createEventManager<EventMap>() {
    const listeners: {
        [K in keyof EventMap]?: Observable<EventMap[K]>
    } = {};

    return {
        listen<EventName extends keyof EventMap>(
            evName: EventName
        ): Observable<EventMap[EventName]> {
            let evListener = listeners[evName];

            if (evListener) return evListener; // <-- Error
            

            evListener = new Observable<EventMap[EventName]>();
            listeners[evName] = evListener;

            return evListener; // <-- Over here, too
        },
        // pretend that I wrote some more code down here
        // like a trigger method or something
    }
}
```

The error is this:

```
Type 'Observable<EventMap[EventName]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Observable<EventMap[EventName]>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Observable<EventMap[EventName]>'.
```

My question is: Shouldn't that if block in the first error line act like a type guard?
I mean, this works:

```js
function maybeUndefined(value: string): string | undefined {
    return value;
}

const str = maybeUndefined('value');

console.log(str.indexOf('v')); // error: str is possibly undefined
if (str) console.log(str.indexOf('v')); // all good
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If looks like type guarding on generics does not exist: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4742

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594468/type-guard-dont-work-with-generic-params

Comment: Using the latest version of TypeScript at the time (4.4.2), the same exact code doesn't produce any compile errors ([see](https://tsplay.dev/mZaDPN)). So, whatever the error was, it was either a bug in TypeScript or a non-obvious quirk of your code. If you still have this error, I'd suggest either updating to the latest version of TypeScript (alternatively, finding a more recent version than yours where this error is fixed) or dig deeper into the code.