# Type guard don't work with generic params?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Example:

```
type SomeType = {
    foo: string;
} | undefined;

function someFn<TParams extends SomeType>(params1: SomeType, params2: TParams): void {
  if (params1) {
    Object.entries(params1);
  }
  if (params2) {
    Object.entries(params2); // here is an error
  }
}
```

TypeScript cannot determine that `params2` does not contain undefined. Is there a logical explanation for this, or is it a mistake in TypeScript?

Online demo [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKCvqAMzjgC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG4cBfKAHygFd6ATCIQYR%20rHIT4BjYLTj1KiCADF6AHmQAFAIbVtCClAgAPYBAGH4SVJAB8ACjC79FAIzkrKNABooTvQYATORazgYAlOQAbnC0-Nh4ULSEUI5hbuEJBFAA8gBGAFYQMgB05jS0EBRpARms%20GyJyan%20LoGZuNn5RaXldFU1beH1UI2NQA)

Comment: This is an open typescript issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open issue in typescript (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4742). Automatic type guards and generics don't always work together. As a possible work around you could define this type guard manually:

```
type SomeType = {
    foo: string;
} | undefined;

function isDefined<T> (v: T): v is Exclude<T, undefined> {
  return v !== undefined
}

function someFn<TParams extends SomeType>(params1: SomeType, params2: TParams): void {
  if (params1) {
    Object.entries(params1);
  }
  if (isDefined(params2)) {
    Object.entries(params2);
  }
}
```